# METAPOST equivalent to TikZ polar coordinates?

Tags: metapost

When drawing with TikZ, I find sometime convenient to use polar coordinates (angle:distance), as in this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   [pole/.style={circle,draw=gray,fill=gray,thick,text width=2cm, align=center}]
  \node[pole] (eur) at (60:3cm) {Europe};
  \node[pole] (afr) at (300:3cm) {Afrique};
  \node[pole] (amq) at (180:3cm)  {Amérique};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I get a similar effect using METAPOST ? I could'nt find direct answer in the manual. I am quite sure one can achieve the same with a good knowledge of geometry. It would be good for scripting.

So far, my METAPOST equivalent would be

```
beginfig(1);
u:=1cm ;
label(btex Amérique etex, (-3u,0) ) ;
label(btex Europe etex, (u,2u) ) ;
label(btex Afrique etex, (u,-2u) ) ;
endfig ;
end
```

Of course this are not polar coordinates and I am even not sure angles are the same as in TikZ.
Since I am not a scientist, I would be glad to have some explanation if some geometry knowledge is required.

Comment: You can easily convert r and φ to cartesian coordinates using the prescription (x,y) = (r\*cos(φ),r\*sin(φ))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `dir` operator.  From the MetaPost manual:

[image]

Here with MetaFun in ConTeXt:

```
\startMPpage
u:=1cm ;
label(btex Amérique etex, 3u*dir 60) ;
label(btex Europe etex, 3u*dir 300) ;
label(btex Afrique etex, 3u*dir 180) ;
\stopMPpage
```

Comment: Thanks. I wouldn't have been able to find this on my own. It's been too long since I learnt what does cos and sin reflect… But now I see the point.

Comment: There is also an operator `angle` that does the opposite, so that `angle dir 60` should return `60`.  A bit like `atan2` in other languages.

Comment: As a matter of style you could also write `3 dir 60 scaled u`.

Comment: @Thruston `angle` does *exactly* perform `atan2` (at least in `double` and `decimal` mode) https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/blob/ca4141d158e3baeee6616b706a008cfe2dc5a2a3/texk/web2c/mplibdir/mpmathdouble.w#L1166-L1183

Comment: Yes quite right. In my old-fashioned British way, when I say “a bit like” I mean “exactly the same as”…